# Socketio & expressjs version issue with node

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Here is peice code on which i'm working to build a socket server. Here i'm using nodejs, socket.io & exress js for this.

```
// File name : app.js
var express = require('express'),   
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);
```

I've 2 version of socket.io & express js. One is bit old & another one is latest one.

In old version when i'm running app.js file in node(by executing command- node app.js) i'm getting the out put like.. " info  - socket.io started". But, in latest version i'm not getting any out put. It's simply giving blank.

Any idea guys, what's the issue with this code ?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Which component's version are you talking about? node.js, express or socket.io? Also, whether or not it logs some output is not a very important thing if all else works.

Comment: Already I've mentioned that. It's, socket.io & express js.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working even. May be, because of some reason socket.io is not working i think.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have specified in 'connection' is shown as output.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     console.log('connected');
}
```

Comment: It's fine. But, i'm not getting the message of "info - socket.io started". Which means, socket.io is not working & i need to it to do my rest of the things.

Comment: Did u get any problem during socket.io npm installation?

Comment: In the client side, are you seeing any errors in the console? like io not defined?

Answer (score 0):

OK!!!, finally I got the reason why, i was not getting this "info - socket.io started" message from my console. It's because, from socket.io 1.0 they've SILENT those debugging info (Ref-http://goo.gl/Zq6u3m).

So, from my latest version of socket.io(version 1.0) i was not getting those debugging info in my console. But, when i was shifting to my old version of socket.io i was getting those debugging info.

Any way, thanks a lot for your quick replies. I really appreciate it.

Thanks and Reagrds